# How to assign boolean value from an object to a variable in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, recaptcha

Hello I am trying to assign the Boolean value of an object (data) obtained from the recaptcha validation. The value of the object is TRUE but assigning it into the variable isn't working and the end it sends it as False.

```
Protected Sub Validate_Captcha(ByRef Validation As Boolean)

    Dim hdk As String = "ITOOKOUTTHESTRING"
    'Dim res As Recaptcha = Recaptcha.RecaptchaResponse()
    Dim Response As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("g-recaptcha-response")
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" & hdk & "&response=" & Response)

    Using wResponse As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using readStream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim jsonResponse As String = readStream.ReadToEnd()
            Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim data As Object = js.Deserialize(Of Object)(jsonResponse)
            js.ConvertToType(Of Object)(data)
            Try
            ''    For Each obj As Object In data
            ''        Validation = Convert.ToBoolean(obj.Success.Value)
                Next

                '' ****************************
                '' THE PROBLEM IS HERE

                Validation = data(0).value

                '' **************************
```

[image]

```
                If Validation = False Then
                    Dim se As New Exception("Object is not validated")
                    Throw se
                End If

            Catch ex As FormatException
                lblError.Text = ex.Message
            Catch ex As InvalidCastException
                lblError.Text = ex.Message
            Catch ex As Exception
                lblError.Text = ex.Message

            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I really like the IDE snapshot right in the middle of your code. You get +1 for this.

Comment: Perhaps you should convert data(0).value (which is an object) to boolean using: Convert.ToBoolean(data(0).value). Sidenote: convert this sub into a function which returns a boolean. Like the example in the linked Codeproject page in djv's answer.

Comment: `data(0).value` looks like it should be a bool. And it looks like you should be able to late-bind it. But what is the type of the objects in `data`? All I see is `System.Collections.Generic...`. Are they KeyValuePairs(Of string, object)? Is data then a Dictionary(Of string, object)? If it is, then you can't key it with an integer. If my answer is not working for you, try `Validation = data("success")`

Answer (score 0):

See [this codeproject page](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/851004/How-to-Validate-Recaptcha-V-Server-side). It looks very similar to your code. Except, this person does the following:

Define a class with a Success string

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property Success As String
End Class
```

Then deserialize to that class instead of object. Access the Success property by converting the string

```
Dim data = js.Deserialize(Of MyObject)(jsonResponse)
Dim valid = Convert.ToBoolean(data.Success)
```